# C: Nicer syntax for generic data structures using void pointers?

Tags: c, syntax, void, void-pointers

I'm currently writing a stack implementation in C. I need it to use as little memory as possible and be as fast as possible while still taking every data type I can throw at it, with multiples types in each stack. I decided to use void pointers for this, and got it working relatively quickly despite my rusty C. However, actually using it is quite ugly.

For testing the stack, I'm pushing integers with a loop. Actually passing the int as a void pointer is the issue.

My first inclination was to use `&`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    stack_push(s, &i); //s is the stack_t pointer
}
```

However with closer inspection this obviously wouldn't work, since `i` is destructively updated every step. Every element in the stack ends up as `20`.

I've since turned to a very ugly solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    int* p = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    *p = i;
    stack_push(s, p);
}
```

This *works*, but presents two issues:

1. It's ugly
2. I have to worry about memory management for every element of the stack. (and for some reason manually walking the stack and freeing every element still leaks memory...)

Is there a better way to do this without wasting unnecessary memory with a union and still being fast? Thanks.

Comment: When you pop items off the stack, how do you know what you have just pulled out? You mention multiple types in each stack, but with just a pointer it will be impossible to tell what type of item it is.

Comment: What's the stack going to be used for? Roughly speaking, a stack is fast at freeing memory because you can just move the stack pointer down. But if the stack just contains pointers into the heap, which all still have to be freed one by one, is a stack still the best solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The pointers you push will usually not be pointers to simple integers, but valid pointers to some kinds of objects. Isn't the caller responsible for managing the memory of those objects? Or are you considering a stack implementation which adopts the responsibility over the pointers and free's them if the stack is destroyed?

Comment: @Douglas This is for an implementation of a stack-based language, so I don't have much choice in data structure type - it needs to at least be pushable, peekable, and popable

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, I'd like something I can just fire-and-forget objects into if I need to.

Comment: @Rotten: Imagine you push heap pointers onto your stack and "forget" about them. Now suppose you `pop` something off the stack. What do you expect to happen? Should the stack free the memory right then? You can't do anything with the `pop`ed object then, so that would be quite useless. Should the stack free the memory later? In that case it needs to remember the object although it's no longer on the stack, so that's not a good option either... Think about what you want here, the question is very unclear. What's the types of objects you want to manage using that stack?

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm not sure actually... I guess I need to think this through a bit more :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types are going to be mixed, something needs to know what the type is.

If it is the client (or user) of the stack who will cast types back to their correct form, then that's fine, but the size still needs to be available to the stack.

If the caller knows that too, the interface might look like:

void push(const int size, void* value);
void pop(const int size, void** valueptr);

I don't think that will be robust in general, but if you are writing a compiler then it can generate all of the correct code, in the same was as the C compiler.

Internaly, I'd have two versions, one for debugging, which retains the value of size, and one for 'performance' which doesn't. I;d wite the debugging one first.

I'd ditch the idea of pointers because

1. it uses extra space
2. the space that is allocated needs to be managed by something.

If the stack stores values, then once popped it has no responsibilty.

An implementation:

```
unsigned char space[BIG];
unsigned char *stack = &space[0];
int top = 0;
void push(const int size, void* value) {
    unsigned char* valp = (char *)value;
    *(int *)stack = size;
    stack += sizeof(int);
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
       *stack++ = *val++;
    }
}
```

pop is the reverse,

Answer (score 2):

if i didn't misunderstand, what you want is a stack that you can put data of every type you want in it. Here is an idea of "struct any". I think this would help.

```
union multitype
{
    int     asInt;
    void    *asVPtr;
    TYPE_A  *asA;
    TYPE_B  *asB;
    ...
}

typedef struct _any {
    int              type;
    union multitype  value;
} Any;

void any_put_int(Any *pAny, int value);
void any_put_v_ptr(Any *pAny, void *value);
void any_put_typeA_ptr(Any *pAny, TYPE_A *value);
void any_put_typeB_ptr(Any *pAny, TYPE_B *value);
...

int     any_get_int(Any *pAny);
void*   any_get_v_ptr(Any *pAny);
TYPE_A* any_get_typeA_ptr(Any *pAny);
TYPE_B* any_get_typeB_ptr(Any *pAny);
...
```

If we got an stack implentation based on struct Any, codes in the question would be like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    Any anAny;
    any_put_int(&anAny, i);
    stack_push(s, anAny); // or stack_push(s, &anAny);
}
```

Comment: My issue with unions is (as far as my knowledge goes) the compiler will pad out all the types to the size of the largest type. 4 or whatever bytes isn't a huge deal with a few elements, but with 1000+ it's definitely not fun.

Comment: @Rotten194 . In most situtation, struct Any takes 8 bytes memory, 4 bytes for type and 4 bytes for data address. Notice that types in union multitype are equal length, they are pointers except one is integer. You need to maintain the memory of most data type. Putting whole data into stack will cost two memory copy, when the data is large, it's not fun either. Unless the data are small size, it's better for a container to hold an address other than the data itself. 4 extra bytes for each object in stack *VS* duplicate data and extra memory copy, which is better depends on the real situation.